# Is there a way to access and copy stdout of octave script?

Tags: octave

I want to run a few octave scripts and record their outputs (whatever is shown in command window) to a text file. Is there a way to do it other than copy and pasting the output from command window to text file.

Edit: Or alternatively how to run an octave program using OS command line and save output in a text file?

Comment: in MATLAB (not sure about Octave), you can call `diary()` to get the output, or call the functions withing `evalc()` as `command_string=evalc(your_fun())` to get the text.

Comment: Octave also has the diary function, see [https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/diary.html](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/diary.html)

Comment: With regard to your alternative, if you're on a linux environment you can use the `script` command, which is effectively the same thing as 'diary', but for the bash terminal. See `man script` for details. Alternatively, you can simply use file redirection, i.e. `octave myscript.m > logfile`

Comment: Might want `&> logfile` instead of `> logfile`, so you capture error output too. Works on Mac too.